# Android nested fragment rendering to main activity

Tags: fragment, android-nested-fragment

How to render the nested fragment to main activity??

This is my hierarchy mainAcivity has three dynamic fragment

Inside RsOneFragment contain another childone fragment so on...

Main Activity -> RsOneFragment  -> ChildOneFragment -> ChildFirstFragment

mainActivity -> RsTwoFragment

mainActivity -> RsThreeFragment

**How to render childFistFragemt to mainActivity**

how to achieve this, please help
Here is my code snippet

```
MainAcivity

fragmentOneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
 FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
 transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim);
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new RsOneFragment());
 transaction.commit();
  }
 });

RsOneFragment extends Fragment:
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle  savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rsslist_overview, container,   false);
    insertNestedFragment();
    return view;
}
private void insertNestedFragment() {
 Fragment fragment = new ChildOneFragment();
 FragmentTransaction transaction   =getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.child_fragment_container_two,  fragment).commit();
}

ChildOneFragment extends Fragment:

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);
childRsOneImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.childRsOneImage);
fragmentContainer = (FrameLayout)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

childRsOneImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim);
transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new ChildFirstFragment());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
}
});
return view;
}
```

childRsOneImage clicking its showing the following error..
    Process: com.example.NestedFragmentsExample, PID: 1885
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080055

```
Hope u would understand my problem...
Any help appreciated..Thanks a lot!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem myself.
  instead of

FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

i replace like this
   FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();

and its working fine...